# How to use group function in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Is there a way to use a group function in the where clause? I'm trying to insert records based on the following logic below, but only for records with qty1 < qty2

My code:

```
    With t1 as (select item_no, qty,
                min (stock_date)
           From stock_tab
          Where stock_date < SYSDATE
        Group by item_no, qty
     Select item_no, min(t1.qty) qty1, max(t2.qty) qty2, max(stock_date)
         From t1
        Where t1.qty1 < t1.qty2  --incorrect
         --    min(t1.qty) < max(t1.qty2)  --also tried this 
         Group by item_no
        Oder by max(t1.stock_date) desc, max(t1.qty) desc
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to use.  It might surprise you, but a non-working query does not necessarily convey your actual intent.

Comment: WHERE clause is used for filtering rows and it applies on each and every row, while HAVING clause is used to filter groups in SQL.

Comment: I may have to re-phrase the question and make up some data set. The one I have now is huge and may not apply here. Stay tuned!

Comment: The column aliased as "qty2" says it's coming from "max(t2.qty)", but there's no data source named "t2".

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use aggregate functions as a filter you are searching for [`having`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

```
With t1 as (select item_no, qty,
            min (stock_date)
       From stock_tab
      Where stock_date < SYSDATE
    Group by item_no, qty)
 Select item_no, min(t1.qty) qty1, max(t2.qty) qty2, max(stock_date)
     From t1
     Group by item_no
     having min(t1.qty) < max(t1.qty2)
    Order by max(t1.stock_date) desc, max(t1.qty) desc
```